# Cannot Running In OS 4.0-6.0

Tags: android

My Application must be in OS 4.0-9.0. But, I have problem is error in OS 4.0-6.0, always force close. Can Somebody help me to resolve this?

Here's my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.application.application"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:1.3.1'


    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
}
```

This Is My Logcat Error.Please Help me to solve this. Thank you.

> 03-04 11:19:46.084 5232-5232/com.application.application
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.application.application, PID: 5232 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.application.application/com.application.application.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error
>   inflating class ImageView at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) Caused
>   by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error
>   inflating class ImageView at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>   at
>   com.application.application.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
>   Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource
>   ID #0x7f080216 at
>   android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233) at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106) at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
>   at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)  at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)  at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>   at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>   at
>   com.application.application.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)  03-04
>   11:19:46.099 1146-1146/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1146:
>   eglCreateSyncKHR(1865): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)

Comment: Please attach your error logcat to your question. It's nearly impossible to help you without the error logcat.

Comment: Please read [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23353173/295004)

Comment: `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080216 at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1233)`, check your resource file.

Comment: `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) at com.application.application.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937) at`, please add your MainActivity and the layout.

Comment: Btw, you can format the error logcat with `Ctrl + K`